# Batch Geocoder API, how to get extra road attributes

Tags: here-api

Using the Batch reverse-Geocoder API, is it possible to get additional road attributes, like:

- SpeedLimit
- LinkFlags
- SideOfStreet

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For getting the side of street you have to first add parameter

> locationattributes=mapReference

and request the output field

> mapReferenceSideOfStreet

in the outcols parameter.

Example:

> &locationattributes=mapReference&outcols=city,district,street,mapReferenceSideOfStreet

Comment: Hi, Thanks!
It works with reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com
but does not seems to work with the batch geocoder. Any chance to have it working there too?

Comment: Ok, I found how to do it :)

Comment: Any chance to get the SpeedCategory?

Comment: Or any of the LinkInfo: FunctionalClass - TravelDirection - SpeedCategory - SpeedLimit - LinkFlags - AccessFlags